# Symfony 2.0 Inter-session communication

Tags: php, session, post, symfony, communication

How to have one session refresh another session? let's say we have a smartphone, a server, and a laptop. Laptop has a current session with server, then smartphone does HTTP POST to server, now we want this event to trigger a refresh in the laptop's session.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear about the specifics of your problem, but assuming you are logged as User X(and your User entity has a field that gets the timestamp on every update e.g: updated_at) both on phone and on laptop, and the phone changes the user address for example, you could get that event over your laptop using ajax by having an action like:

```
class SomeController extends Controller {
      //...
      /**
        * checks if entity was updated since
        *
        * @Route("/check/{id}/{tstamp}", name="entity_check")
        * @Template()
        */
        public function checkAction($id, $tstamp) {
           //check if anything updated by comparing entity's updated_at against $tstamp
           //...
           //as the user locale may differ from server's, send back the timestamp too
           $data['last_update'] = time();
           return new Response(json_encode($data));
        }
}
```

and the javascript for the twig file:

```
<script>
var last_check = {{ "now"|date("t") }};
setInterval(function() { 
             $.ajax( "{{ url('route_to_your_check_action', {'id': entity.id, 'last_check':''}) }}/" + last_check )
             .done(function(data) { 
                         var info = $.parseJSON(data);
                         last_check = info.last_update;
                         //if anything changed refresh on user side 
                   })
             .fail(function() { //on error do something if needed 
                   });
           }
           , 12000); // make this call every 12 seconds
</script>
```

hope it helps.